# Java Set Iterator#remove() or Set#clear() afterwards?

Tags: java, iterator, set, hashset

I have for example a `Set<Object> objects` or more specific `objects = new HashSet<>()`.

Now I want to iterate over the set, invoke something for each element and then remove the element from the set.

```
Iterator<Object> iterator = objects.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object object = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(object));
    iterator.remove();
}
```

Is it better (faster, more readable, more preferable) to use `Set#clear()` afterwards instead of using `Iterator#remove()` inside the loop?

```
for (Object object : objects) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(object));
}

objects.clear();
```

Comment: Can you define "better"?

Comment: it is probably faster to use `clear`, maybe not enough to *feel* any difference, in that sample code... but maybe you want/need to keep unprocessed elements if something (Exception) happens in the loop. IMHO the 2nd looks better (less code, two distinct functionality)

Comment: @RoyShahaf edited.

Comment: Well, to add on what Carlos said:
1. both approaches yield similar speed
2. 2nd option is more readble (this is opinionated)
3. 1st approach is good when you want to guarantee at-most once behavior and 2nd approach is good when you want to guarantee at-least once behavior

Comment: Consider the possibility of not clearing the set at all. If you don't need it any more, just let the garbage collector dispose of it; clearing it won't help. If you need an empty set, consider making a new empty set.

Comment: @user2357112 has a point

Comment: `objects` should be a final field.

Comment: Can you say why it should be final?

Comment: Not sure if final is the best prescription in this context. Maybe @stonar96 meant *immutable*?
Roy: If you have a classroom full of children and give each one a candy, you don't empty the classroom (in bulk like *clear* or one by one by *remove*) to give sweets to another set of children. You just leave one classroom and get into another. ;-)

Also, consider *foreach* loop.

Comment: @Piohen: I wasn't disagreeing with user2357112

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it better (faster, more readable, more preferable) to use `Set#clear()` afterwards instead of using `Iterator#remove()` inside the loop?

There is no reason to think that the `clear()` method would be any slower than removing all the elements individually via the iterator.  Even if it were implemented naively, you would expect to at least save on method invocation overhead.  In practice, `clear()` has an opportunity to be much more efficient.

But looking at it from a performance perspective is probably premature.  This is unlikely to be a bottleneck in your code, so making it faster is unlikely to produce a noticeable difference.  But you won't know for sure unless you test the performance via a profiler.

Usually it is best to focus first on functionality, and second on clarity and simplicity.  Consider issues such as what should happen if you abort in the middle of iterating over the set: is it right for some, but not all, elements to then have been removed?  Or do you need the original size of the set for anything?  Etc.  Perform performance optimizations only when and where measurements demonstrate a potential for improvement.

If indeed both approaches are equally good from a functionality perspective, then allow me to observe that using `clear()` affords an even better simplification than just removing the `Iterator.remove()` invocation from the loop: you can rewrite the loop as an enhanced `for` loop or a stream pipeline.

The question already demonstrates the enhanced `for` alternative; here's the streams one:

```
objects.stream()
       .forEach(o -> System.out.println(String.valuef(o)));
objects.clear();
```

Both of these have considerable clarity advantages over your original `Iterator`-based code.